# groovy: split a string but include the delimiter

Tags: string, groovy

I want to split a string about a delimiter, but I want the delimiter to be included in the output.  For example:

```
> String s = "helloXthereXmyXfriend"
> s.split("X")
["hello","Xthere","Xmy","Xfriend"]
```

Is there a method that does this, or do I need to write my own?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that works

```
String[] split(String s, String regex) {
    String[] split = s.split(regex);
    String[] out = Arrays.stream(split)
        .map(x -> regex + x)
        .toArray(String[]::new);
    out[0] = split[0];
    return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a method that does this, but you could use meta-programming to add your own:

```
String.metaClass.splitInclude { delimiter ->
    def tokens = delegate.split(delimiter) as List
    def result = tokens.withIndex().collect { item, index ->
                    (index) ? "${delimiter}${item}" : item 
                 } 
}

def s = "helloXthereXmyXfriend"
def result = s.splitInclude('X')
assert ["hello","Xthere","Xmy","Xfriend"] == result
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for post-processing by Groovy code. Regex has enough power to
do the task on its own. Try this regex:

```
.+?(?=X|$)
```

How it works:

- `.+?` - Match non-empty sequence of characters, as little as possible.
- `(?=X|$)` - Positive lookup: After what you have just matched there is
  either `X` (your pattern) or the end of the string.

In Groovy the task is now not to split the source string,
but find all matches.

Try this code:

```
String s = "helloXthereXmyXfriend"
def tbl = s.findAll('.+?(?=X|$)')
print tbl
```

Note that I changed double quotes around the regex to single quotes,
to prevent interpolation of variables.

It prints:

```
[hello, Xthere, Xmy, Xfriend]
```